# Global app remote notification response ios

Tags: ios, uibutton, push-notification

I would like to implement a similar response system for push notifications throughout my app. When a remote notification appears and the application is in the active state I would like to place a button temporarily on the screen that performs the same action regardless of where it is in the app. 
The only way I can think to do this is to create the same response to notification method in each of the app's many view controller. 
Is there any way to do this in the app delegate, tab bar, or navigation bar so that the same response would apply to multiple views rather than placing the same function in each view controller separately?
Please advise and thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly: your problem is not related to notifications at all, but rather how to place a button on top of all views. A common way would be to add it as a subView to the window.

As a starting point: [AwesomeMenu on GitHub](https://github.com/levey/AwesomeMenu)